# java.lang.VerifyError for API<20

Tags: java, android, verifyerror

I've made an app which supports fingerprint security. All works fine as long as I run it on API greater than API 19. Of course fingerprint is only supported in devices since Marshmallow so I surrounded everything which have to do with fingerprint with
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {}
I got following Error:

```
 java.lang.VerifyError: com/myapp/newapp/Introduction
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
    at        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've enclose it, to be caused by this part of code:

```
try {                                                               
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                    null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            //Return true if the cipher has been initialized successfully//
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {

            //Return false if cipher initialization failed//
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
                | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
```

I dont know how to solve it.